# Unable to parse some content from page source using requests and re

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-re

I'm trying to parse deal details from a webpage using requests and re module. The content I wish to grab is within some script tag in page source. When I tried with the attempt below I get a portion of the content. However, I wish to get the full content which is from `dealDetails` to `responseMetadata`.

[webpage link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb)

I've tried with:

```
import re
import requests

link = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb'

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
deals = re.findall(r"dealDetails[^{]+(.*?}),[\s\S]+responseMetadata",r.text,re.DOTALL)[0]
print(deals)
```

Output that it currently produces is [this](https://pastebin.com/FJ15wz2R).

Output that I wish to grab is [this](https://pastebin.com/Dc7vMCvx).

***How can I get the aforesaid content using requests and re?***

Comment: Don't post output/code from other sources. If that source stops working, then the question / answers will be less useful in the future. If any code / output is necessary for the question, post it in a separate code-block in the question-body.

Comment: If I try like this `re.findall(r"dealDetails[^{]+(.*?)responseMetadata",r.text,re.DOTALL)`, it works but includes the last `,` and `"` which I don't want. However, I wish to get the desired portion using regex in the first place without post processing.

Comment: I'm seeing this post pretty late, has your problem been solved or are you still seeking a solution?

Comment: Nope, it's not solved yet. Thanks for asking @Robo Mop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahem ahem, let's just assume I'm not an idiot and I didn't confuse the output you wanted vs the output you were getting.

Moving right along, here's what I did:

```
\"dealDetails\"\s*:\s*\{[\n\r\s]+(.+?)(?=,?[\n\r\s]+\"responseMetadata\")
```

As seen here at **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YAnUNm/3)**

## Explanation:

I'm using positive lookaheads, which tells the regex that at a certain position, something should be following that position in the text. In our case, the match should end at a position which is followed by a comma, multiple newlines and spaces, and finally `"responseMetadata"`. As you can see in the link provided, the entire match is dealDetails until its end, and the **second group** is the output you want.

<s>Again, let's assume I'm just unable to read and that's why I messed up the output you got vs what you expected</s>

Comment: It appears to be working in the right way. It's a huge one by the way.